# <input type="date"> event listener: How to distinguish mouse select vs. keyboard input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the native HTML date pickers. I want to achieve that the parent form is submitted when a date is selected by the datepickers browsers provide.
If the date is input by keyboard, I only want to submit if the enter key is pressed or on focusout.

Now my problem is that I cannot distinguish between date picker input and keyboard input, at least in Firefox. Some examples:

```
$(this).on('input', function(event) {
    console.log(event.type);
}
```

This always logs 'input', no matter what I do - I would have expected that to be either "click" or "keydown" or something alike.

The on('click') handler only fires when I click on the input field, not when I click something in the date picker...

Can someone push me in the right direction?

Thanks alot
Philipp

Comment: Other events like paste, or key events will also trigger input event but the only event you are actually listening for is `input`. Did you try `change` event?

Comment: Basically, you can't know what caused the input when listening to the input event (since the argument does not have the properties needed, like the [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property of `KeyboardEvent`). If you want to distinguish between event sources, listen for the types of events triggered by those sources.

Comment: It sounds like you're going to need make a non-native date picker and bind listeners to the specific sections of the picker that you want to listen for changes in.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey that was my basic idea after input event listener did not what I hoped. But: click event handler does not fire when something is selected in the date picker. Otherwise I would have attached a click and keyup event listener...

Comment: @charlietfl the change event fires as wanted, but I do not find a way inside the change event handler to distinguish where the change came from... maybe there is but I cant find one.

Comment: Shouldn't matter does it? Really think you'll need another trigger to use for submit personally. Note that having a submit button/input in a form with one other input will submit when enter is pressed

Comment: You could try setting a flag in a keyboard event and in the input event check for the flag. If it's not set, you know it was a mouse event. Hard to give good advice, since I'm not sure why you want to distinguish between the event sources in the first place.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I want to distinguish because my form has some autosave implemented. If a text field is changed, is either submitted when focus is lost or when enter key is pressed.
Now for the date fields, the best UX imho would be if the form is submitted when a date is selected via the date picker or if the focus is lost. Its just strange when you select something in the date picker and nothing happens.
Submitting on change is not an option, because this will submit each time the user presses a key, if he decides to type the date and not use the date picker.

Answer (score 1):

I did a workaround which is close to what I want:

```
 $('#eooMainForm input[type="date"]')
    .each(function() {
            $(this).data('serialized', $(this).serialize());
            $(this).on('focusout', function() {
                if($(this).serialize() != $(this).data('serialized')) {
                    $("#eooMainForm").form('submit');
                }
            });

            $(this).on('keypress', function(event) {
                $(this).data('byKeyPress', 1);
            });

            $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                $(this).data('byKeyPress', 0);
            });

            $(this).on('change', function(event) {
                //if change was done by date picker click
                if($(this).data('byKeyPress') != 1 && $(this).serialize() != $(this).data('serialized')) {
                    $("#eooMainForm").form('submit');
                }
            });
    });
```

So a keypress event listener sets the "flag" "byKeyPress" to 1, while a click events listener sets it to zero. This way, I can determine in the change event listener what caused the change.
The only situation where this does not work is when a user starts typing the date but then selects it by clicking the datepicker. I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to attach an event which supports both event types. Using JQuery:
  `$('a.save').bind('mousedown keypress', submitData(event, this));`

Then create a JS condition:

```
 function submitData(event, id)
{
    if(event.type == 'mousedown')
    {
        // do something
        return;
    }
    if(event.type == 'keypress')
    {
        // do something else
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the basic idea is good, but unfortunately the mousedown event is not fired when some date is selected in the date picker.

Comment: This also won't work, since you're calling `submitData` once, when you bind the event handler, at which point `event` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the list of event in this image.

[image: jQuery Event List]

```js
$('input').on('blur', function(event) {
    alert(event.type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
```

You can apply all `event` like the above example. Above example applied `blur event` on `input`.